# Instead of getting array elements as output ,I'm getting array address(Output:[I@59494225) in scala----In the below code I expect output as (2,1)

Tags: arrays, scala

Here the requirement is to compare both the array elements a(i) and b(i). And update the

> If a[i]>b[i] , then a is awarded 1 point 
>  If b[i]>a[i] , then  b
>   is awarded 1 point

```
object MyWizard extends App {
    def compareTriplets(a:Array[Int],b:Array[Int]):Array[Int]= {
        var aCount=0
        var bCount=0
        for(i<-0 to a.length-1){
            for(j<-0 to b.length-1){
                if(i==j) {
                    if(a(i)>b(i)){
                        aCount=aCount+1
                    }else if(a(i)<b(i)){
                        bCount=bCount+1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val c:Array[Int]=Array(aCount,bCount)
        c
    }
    println(compareTriplets(Array(1,32,3),Array(453,2,1)))
}
```

Comment: That is the way **Arrays** are printed. You can use `array.mkString("[", ", ", "]")` to get a nice string representation of your data. Or do not use **Arrays*+ but rather a **List** which is a more high level and idiomatic data structure in Scala. Also, I would recommend you to do not use mutability and loops, but higher-order functions or recursion. Also, if the result always has two elements do not return a collection. but a tuple. Also, it seems you are not that versed in Scala, I would recommend you to follow some tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more efficient, idiomatic, generic and simpler implementation of your algorithm.

```
// This works for any type as long as we know how to compare instances of it.
def compareTriplets[T : Ordering](as: List[T], bs: List[T]): (Int, Int) = {
  import Ordering.Implicits._ // Provides the comparison operators.

  (as lazyZip bs).foldLeft((0, 0)) {
    case ((aCount, bCount), (a, b)) =>
      if (a > b) (aCount + 1, bCount)
      else if (a < b) (aCount, bCount + 1)
      else (aCount, bCount)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping.
But lazyZip is throwing compilation error even after importing import Ordering Implicits.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar ah sorry, `laxyZip` was added on `2.13` if you are in an older version, just use `zip`.

Answer (score -1):

use a toString() method because it is being interpreted as its data address, not a string format of the data. 
Here is a simple geeksForGeeks example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-map-tostring-method-with-example/

Comment: `pritnln` always calls `toString` the problem is that the `toString` of an **Array** prints its address instead of its values, because of **Java** geniuses.